# using regular expressions to find and remove json code

Tags: json, regex, replace, scada-ignition

I need to delete over 100,000 tags in a project with ignition. I decide the best way would be to download the json of the files and delete all instances of consistent tags in different devices. Example:
I need to delete this tag (and others) in hundreds of devices, they will be identical to all the others accept for the FV5003 where it could be PP2340 or AG7698.

```
            {
              "valueSource": "opc",
              "opcItemPath": "ns\u003d1;s\u003d[PPD]FV5003_HOA.State.IO_Open",
              "dataType": "Boolean",
              "name": "IO_Open",
              "tagType": "AtomicTag",
              "opcServer": "Ignition OPC UA Server"
            },
```

Is there a way to delete all instances like this making FV5003 a wild card in regular expressions.
I have zero experience in regex. Also I am using vscode.

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: JSON is not regular language. It is context independent language. But regular language is a subset of context independent language. So, you can't use regular expressions to remove json.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code isn't really relevant. I just want to delete everything within the brackets. Is there no tool to delete using a wild card?

Comment: Do you mean something like e.g. [`{[^}{]*?\[PPD\](?:FV5003|PP2340|AG7698)_[^}{]*},` (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/2czrPp/1)? If so, is there always a `[PPD]` before and an underscore after to identify? Can there occur any braces inside the block...

Comment: well part numbers were just examples. Id like to delete all as I have serveral hundred part numbers

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove all of the 'IO open' opc tags? I want to make sure I understand the procedure you are using. You are exporting your OPC tags and deleting the tags from Ignition. Then, you are modifying the JSON file to remove the tags named 'IO Open,' and finally, you are importing the JSON file back into Ignition?

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '
  del(
    .. |
    select(type=="object") |
    select(has("opcItemPath")) |
    select(
      .opcItemPath|
      test("\\Ans\u003d1;s\u003d\\[PPD\\].*_HOA.State.IO_Open\\Z")
    )
  )
' input.json
```

- `..` - walk the structure
- `select`:

  - objects
  - that contain an attribute named `opcItemPath`
  - whose value matches the `test` regex
- `del`ete them

---

Or, to "delete everything within the brackets":

```
jq '
  (
    .. |
    select(
      .opcItemPath |
      test("\\Ans\u003d1;s\u003d\\[PPD\\].*_HOA.State.IO_Open\\Z")
    )?
  ) |= {}
' input.json
```

- `|=` - update selected objects to be empty object `{}`
- `?` - discard errors that might arise from eliding the first two `select` filters